# Does spacetime exists inside matter?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

Does spacetime exits inside matter like in the atom or molecule? If yes,my other question would be as electron moves inside atom, can it create gravitational waves(I know they will be very small in amplitude) ?

If it's yes to both the questions(I don't know this is right or not),then I think properties of light such as absorption,emission,transmission can be explained on the basis of gravitational waves. If a photon strikes the crest of the gravitational wave produced by the electron,the photon bounces back(photon is too light that it can be deflected by small amplitude of gravitational wave produced by electron) , if photon strikes the trough of the gravitational wave then it is transmitted and if photon doesn't strike either crest or trough of the gravitational wave i.e. it strikes at a point where both crest and trough cancel out, the photon is absorbed.

I think photon behaves as particles,but the wave-like behavior of photon is due to gravitational waves(i.e. gravity).
What you guys think?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Please phrase your question in terms of mainstream physics concepts and present a coherent reasoning.

Comment: For the time being, it would make more sense if you wrote about the electromagnetic force instead of gravity. Please notice that the waves are more-or-less probabilities, so mentioning "crests" should be replaced with a higher probability of finding a particle in the specific region of space-time, so if the phases of waves are aligned, the interaction of these "probability" waves should be higher etc.

Answer (score 1):

The $s$-orbital is spherically symmetric and thus its angular momentum should not generate any sort of gravitational waves. According to your theory, atoms should never be able to excite out of an s-orbital. That's experimentally wrong.

If the $s$-orbital is not spherically symmetric (contrary to what experiments show), but involves a classical particle orbiting a nucleus by classical electromagnetism laws, then it is a well-known prediction of classical electromagnetism that the electrons of all of the S-orbitals will experience a severe orbital decay due to the Larmor radiation formula, reaching the nucleus in some very short time (my memory says microseconds, but I'm not sure). This would likewise kill chemistry.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! - I have one more question,do gravitational waves exist inside atom or molecule due to electron or nucleus etc?

Comment: We have no hope of being able to detect such things within our lifetimes, and present theory is not very accomodating to both quantum mechanics and general relativity at any simultaneous time, so I cannot answer that question well. Nonetheless, it seems the answer is probably "yes", as any "no" answer could potentially make atoms into either a perfect absorber or reflector of gravitational waves, which would probably be bad theory-wise.